# Wolfram Mathematica ONLINE does not give me the solution for the following integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have some problem in Mathematica and I could not evaluate the following integral. There is a closed-form solution for the following. Can someone please give me the result.

```
α = 4;
A = Pi*λ*P^(2/α)*Gamma[1+2/α]*Gamma[1-2/α];
Integrate[x*Exp[-t*x]*A*Exp[-A^2/[4*x]]/[2*Pi^(1/2)*x^(3/2)],{x,0,B}]
```

Comment: There are syntax errors in that snippet. Use of square brackets where parens are what was wanted.

Comment: In particular this variant might give a viable result. Note that assumptions are provided so `Integrate` can deduce convergence. `Integrate[
 x*Exp[-t*x]*A*Exp[-A^2/(4*x)]/(2*Pi^(1/2)*x^(3/2)), {x, 0, B}, 
 Assumptions -> {B > 0, A > 0, Element[t, Reals]}]`

Answer (score 2):

```
α = 4;
A = Pi*λ*P^(2/α)*Gamma[1 + 2/α]*Gamma[1 - 2/α];
```

In addition to correcting the syntax, some assumptions on the parameters are needed

```
int1 = Assuming[{B > 0, P > 0, Element[λ, Reals]},
  Integrate[x*Exp[-t*x]*A*Exp[-A^2/(4*x)]/(2*Pi^(1/2)*x^(3/2)), {x, 0, B}]]
```

[image]

Adding the additional assumption that `t` is positive

```
int2 = Assuming[{B > 0, P > 0, t > 0, Element[λ, Reals]},
  Integrate[x*Exp[-t*x]*A*Exp[-A^2/(4*x)]/(2*Pi^(1/2)*x^(3/2)), {x, 0, B}]]
```

[image]

Adding the further additional assumption that `λ` is non-negative

```
int3 = Assuming[{B > 0, P > 0, t > 0, λ >= 0},
  Integrate[x*Exp[-t*x]*A*Exp[-A^2/(4*x)]/(2*Pi^(1/2)*x^(3/2)), {x, 0, B}]]
```

[image]

So the result will depend on which assumptions (above or others) are consistent with your problem.

For an infinite upper limit of integration

```
int4 = Assuming[{P > 0, t > 0, λ >= 0},
  Integrate[
   x*Exp[-t*x]*A*Exp[-A^2/(4*x)]/(2*Pi^(1/2)*x^(3/2)), {x, 0, ∞}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Its great! I would appreciate if you run the above code just for once. I want to change the upper limit of the integration. You better use {x,0,infinity} in place of {x,0,B}.

Comment: Then the output becomes a function of variable t. Then please integrate that function putting {t,0,B}. Please do this for me. It is really very important for me.

Comment: @Dimitrios - if it is really important to you then you should do the work -- this is rather straightforward.

Comment: I mentioned that I have some problem in Mathematica. I am using WOLFRAM Mathematica Online. I do not know why it is not working.

Comment: @Dimitrios - then contact support for Mathematica online.

Comment: Thank you very much for your support and suggestions.